# Visual Studio Macro to Format all Files in a Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, macros

I've recently settled on a new format style for my code and want to replace the existing code.  The only problem is there's 100's if not 1000's of files in my solution and i don't fancy formatting each one individually.

I was wondering how to create a macro to open every file in the solution that has the .cs file extension and simply select all the text and then cut and paste it (which would format it accordingly).  It would also be great if it could sort and removing the using statements aswell but this is not that important as i'd imagine this would be a little harder.

I'd appreciate your help.  Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931406/formatting-at-once-all-the-files-in-a-visual-studio-project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved!  The following macro did the trick incase anyone is interested:

```
   Public Module FormatAll
        Public Sub FormatAll()
            Dim sol As Solution = DTE.Solution
            For i As Integer = 1 To sol.Projects.Count
                Dim proj As Project = sol.Projects.Item(i)
                For j As Integer = 1 To proj.ProjectItems.Count
                    FormatSome(proj.ProjectItems.Item(j))
                Next
            Next
        End Sub

        Private Sub FormatSome(ByVal projectItem As ProjectItem)
            If projectItem.Kind = Constants.vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFile Then
                If projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".cs") = projectItem.Name.Length - 3 Then
                    Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)
                    window.Activate()
                    projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument")
                    projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.RemoveAndSort")
                    window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)
                End If
            End If

            For i As Integer = 1 To projectItem.ProjectItems.Count
                FormatSome(projectItem.ProjectItems.Item(i))
            Next
        End Sub
    End Module
```

Comment: The source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinpilchbisson/archive/2004/05/17/133371.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2008 you have to change the format statements, because FormatDocument is not available:

```
projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatSelection")
```

So the script should be:

```
Public Sub FormatAll()
    Dim sol As Solution = DTE.Solution
    For i As Integer = 1 To sol.Projects.Count
        Dim proj As Project = sol.Projects.Item(i)
        For j As Integer = 1 To proj.ProjectItems.Count
            FormatSome(proj.ProjectItems.Item(j))
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FormatSome(ByVal projectItem As ProjectItem)
    If projectItem.Kind = Constants.vsProjectItemKindPhysicalFile Then
        If projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".cpp") = projectItem.Name.Length - 4 Then
            Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)
            window.Activate()
            projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
            projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatSelection")
            window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)
        ElseIf projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".h") = projectItem.Name.Length - 2 Then
            Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)
            window.Activate()
            projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
            projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatSelection")
            window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)
        End If
    End If

    For i As Integer = 1 To projectItem.ProjectItems.Count
        FormatSome(projectItem.ProjectItems.Item(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. There is a small bug in this code. It should be:
`ElseIf projectItem.Name.LastIndexOf(".h") = projectItem.Name.Length - 2`

Answer (score 1):

There's a new way to format all files in a solution without using a macro using the `dotnet` CLI:

1. Install [dotnet format](https://github.com/dotnet/format/) by running the following command:
   `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format`
2. Run it, replacing `SolutionFile.sln` with the path to your solution file, with the following command line:
   `dotnet format SolutionFile.sln`