# Visual Studio Macro: How to format xml files?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, formatting, visual-studio-macros, envdte

I derived a small macro script from [Visual Studio Macro to Format all Files in a Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942958) but unfortunately it doesn't work with xml, xaml, config etc. All `ProjectItem` that are xml-based normally throw an exception (command not available) when they were opened in their primary view `vsViewKindPrimary`:

```
Dim projectItem As ProjectItem ' actually this is a parameter of a sub'
Dim window As Window = projectItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindPrimary)
window.Activate()
projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument")
window.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes) ' actually this is part of a finally block'
```

Results in:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Command "Edit.FormatDocument" is not available.
 at EnvDTE.DTEClass.ExecuteCommand(String CommandName, String CommandArgs)
```

When opening them as text with `vsViewKindTextView` they stay as they are, although the `Edit.FormatDocument` could be executed.

Is there another command that must be used for xml files? Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Please add English translation of any German messages as SO is mostly English questions and answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue, but have a slightly different repro. This code works for .cpp files, but not .xml files:

```
EnvDTE.Solution soln = System.Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.Solution.11.0")) as EnvDTE.Solution;

soln.DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(file);
soln.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument");
```

If I replace the last line with the following, it leaves the file unchanged:

```
TextSelection selection = soln.DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as TextSelection;
selection.SelectAll();
selection.SmartFormat();
```

I've tried for a while but can't find a work-around.