# Inserting standard comment blocks

Tags: visual-studio

I have inherited a project that has a large number of source files. I need to add a standard comment block at the top of each of the files.

Anyone know a quick way of doing this in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to do that for you. See [Visual Studio Macro to Format all Files in a Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942958/visual-studio-macro-to-format-all-files-in-a-solution) for some code you could use.

Comment: I am using VS2008 Express, so macros are not an option. Will be upgrading to VS2010 professional in the near future so will deal with it then.