# Regex to replace spaces with tabs at the start of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to be able to fix a Text File's tabs/spaces indentation.

Currently each line has spaces in random locations for some reason.

For example:

`space` `tab` `if` -> `tab` `if`

`space` `tab` `space` `tab` `if` -> `tab` `tab` `if`

`tab` `tab` `space` `if` -> `tab` `tab` `if`

etc.

It should not affect anything after the first word, so only the indentation will be affected: So `tab space if space boolean` should be changed to `tab if space boolean` not `tab if tab boolean`.

The regex command should keep the correct number of tabs and just remove the spaces.

If there are 4 spaces in a row it should be converted to a tab instead:

`space` `space` `space` `space` -> `tab`

Thank you for your help. If you could also explain how your regex works it would be very much appreciated as I'm trying to learn how to do my own regex instead of always asking others to do it.

If you need any more information or details please ask I'll respond as quickly as I can.

---

I can accomplish this for a single case at a time like so:

For spaces first: Find: `space*if` Replace: `if` This only works for lines with no tabs and where the first word is if so I would do this for the starting word of the line.

Then I would repeat with `space*\tif`.

Looks like I can match a word without capturing by doing `(?:[A-Za-z])` So I can just swap out the `if` for this and it'll work better.

Comment: Can you link your document here?

Comment: What kind of *document*? Do you mean *text file*? Have you made any effort to do this yourself?

Comment: @FranklinSatler no but I can create an example one, how are files normally attached on SO?

Comment: @KenWhite yes it's a text file (pp to be precise) of programming code. Yes I can do it, but only one case at a time, I do this: Find: `space` `*sub` Replace: `sub`

Comment: A *document* can mean many things (eg., Word .doc, Open Office file, HTML file, etc.), and the distinction is extremely relevant to your question. If you mean *text file*, say *text file*. If you've made an effort to solve this yourself, say so in the question so it's not just a *here's a problem. Write the solution for me so I don't have to do anything* post. :-)

Comment: I had trouble today removing only TWO spaces from the start of a Notepad++ line while replacing within a selection.  It seemed to apply the regexp over and over to the line until all the spaces were gone. Inserting a mark like REPLACEME at the start of each line and then replacing `^REPLACEME[ ][ ]` with nothing achieved my goal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could probably do this in one step, but I'm more partial to simple approaches.

Translate the 4 spaces to tabs first. First line is the match, second is the replace.

```
^(\s*)[ ]{4}(\s*)
$1\t$2
```

Then replace all remaining single spaces with nothing.

```
^(\t*)[ ]+
$1
```

You don't need the square brackets in this case, but it's a little hard to be sure that there's a space, even with SO's code formatting.

The first line searches for the start of the line `^`, then finds any amount of whitespace (including tabs) and puts them in a matching group later named `$1` with `(\s*)`. The middle finds exactly four spaces `[ ]{4}`. The last part repeats the matching group in case there are tabs or more spaces on that side, too.

Since the second match is supposed to be finding all the remaining spaces, the second just looks for 0 or more tabs, puts them in a capture group, and then finds any remaining spaces left. Since it finds and replaces as it goes along, it gobbles up all spaces and replaces with tabs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there's a tab before the space does it?

Comment: Woah it works! Could you explain how it all works please. :) Thanks.

Comment: How can `[   ]{4}` match anything if you just matched all the spaces with `\s*`?

Comment: Depending on your parser, it might. N++ isn't as greedy as, say, sed, so it typically works to do things without specifying that the match should be the shortest possible match.

Your intuition about it is right, though. If you want to be very sure that it matches the smallest amount of whitespace until exactly 4 spaces, have the match group be `(\s*?)` instead.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful answer! I just want to emphasize that to convert all the spaces you should repeat 'find and replace' operation several times.